# Python multiprocessing Manger OSError "Only one usage of each socket address"

Tags: python, multiprocessing-manager

I am creating a communication platform in python (3.4.4) and using the **multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager** class. I have isolated the problem to the code below.

The intention is to have a *ROVManager(role='server')* instance running in one process on the main computer and providing read/write capabilities to the *system* dictionary for multiple *ROVManager(role='client')* instances running on the same computer and a ROV (remotely operated vehicle) connected to the same network. This way, multiple clients/processes can do different tasks like reading sensor values, moving motors, printing, logging etc, all using the same dictionary. *start_reader()* below is one of those clients.

### Code

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys    

class ROVManager(BaseManager):
    def __init__(self, role, address, port, authkey=b'abc'):
        super(ROVManager, self).__init__(address=(address, port),
                                         authkey=authkey)
        if role is 'server':
            self.system = {'shutdown': False}
            self.register('system', callable=lambda: self.system)
            server = self.get_server()
            server.serve_forever()
        elif role is 'client':
            self.register('system')
            self.connect()    

def start_server(server_ip, port_var):
    print('starting server')
    ROVManager(role='server', address=server_ip, port=port_var)    

def start_reader(server_ip, port_var):
    print('starting reader')
    mgr = ROVManager(role='client', address=server_ip, port=port_var)
    i = 0
    while not mgr.system().get('shutdown'):
        sys.stdout.write('\rTotal while loops: {}'.format(i))
        i += 1    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_p = mp.Process(target=start_server, args=('0.0.0.0', 5050))
    reader_p = mp.Process(target=start_reader, args=('127.0.0.1', 5050))
    server_p.start()
    reader_p.start()
    while True:
        # Check system status, restart processes etc here
        pass
```

### Error

This results in the following output and error:

```
starting server
starting reader
Total while loops: 15151
Process Process - 2:
Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "c:\python34\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
    File "c:\python34\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run 
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "C:\git\eduROV\error_test.py", line 29, in start_reader
        while not mgr.system().get('shutdown'):
    File "c:\python34\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 640, in temp
        token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
    File "c:\python34\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 532, in _create
        conn = self._Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
    File "c:\python34\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 496, in Client
        c = SocketClient(address)
    File "c:\python34\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 629, in SocketClient
        s.connect(address)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address(protocol / network address / port) is normally permitted
```

### My research

*Total while loops* are usually in the range 15000-16000. From my understanding it seems like a socket is created and terminated each time *mgr.system().get('shutdown')* is called. Windows then runs out of available sockets. I can't seem to find a way to set *socket.SO_REUSEADDR*.

Is there a way of solving this, or isn't Managers made for this kind of communication? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As error suggests  `Only one usage of each socket address` in general , you can/should bind only a single process to a socket ( unless you design your application accordingly, by passing `SO_REUSEADDR` option while creating socket)
.   These lines

```
server_p = mp.Process(target=start_server, args=('0.0.0.0', 5050))
reader_p = mp.Process(target=start_reader, args=('127.0.0.1', 5050))
```

creates two processes on same port `5050` & so the error.
You can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621(v=vs.85).aspx) to learn how to use `SO_REUSEADDR` & its implications but i am quoting the main part which should get you going

> The second socket calls setsockopt with the optname parameter set to
>   SO_REUSEADDR and the optval parameter set to a boolean value of TRUE
>   before calling bind on the same port as the original socket. Once the
>   second socket has successfully bound, the behavior for all sockets
>   bound to that port is indeterminate. For example, if all of the
>   sockets on the same port provide TCP service, any incoming TCP
>   connection requests over the port cannot be guaranteed to be handled
>   by the correct socket — the behavior is non-deterministic.

Comment: Okey, my intention was to have one server process, and multiple client processes on the same machine and a remote one to communicate with the server. What would be a better approach? Can the server listen at multiple ports? Thanks.

Comment: @MartinLøland  whats the relation between the `master` & `client` process that are on the same machine? maybe if possible can you define the actual flow what each part is supposed to do?

Comment: I have update the original question to reflect my end goal

Comment: @MartinLøland i think you have got the design wrong way. ideally there should be a **single** `server` ( in your case bound on `5050` port) acepting all the remote connections & when you recieve a remote connection you spin up a new process using multiprocessing module & these new processes has the logic processing part (in your case, granting read/write permissions)

Comment: I am trying to follow the documentation at [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager) I am creating a single server process, and then multiple client processes using the *connect()* method as described in the docs. Your description seems logical for a typical server which handles put/get requests, but I thought the BaseManager handled this part of the logics for me?

Comment: @MartinLøland put/get is part of `HTTP` protocol. the design that I mentioned isn't bound to a protocol. it applies to  `TCP` as well &  suits to your requirements based on what you have described